# edit django's generated javascript files

Tags: javascript, python, django

i'm not actually sure that want i want to do is doable, so i'm asking to people with more experience in Python/Django than me: what i have is a local instance of a django web app, i don't have the django files but only the css/js generated from that (specifically, is an [Reviewboard](https://www.reviewboard.org/) instance). I'd like to change some frontend behavior, like not giving the possibility to the users to put themself as reviewer. What i want to do is simply not to show the option in the frontend (i don't care about backend). I tried to edit some js files (only adding console.log) but seems that the code that i'm editing is never running, so i guess that django use some built method to link the files in the app.

Anyone can give me a clue if what i want to do is possible (and how)?

Cheers

Comment: Is there a specific url you want to change? Or is it multiple pages

Comment: You may override static files by creating a similar directory structure with a root bearing the name of the app. You may refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: @BenBeirut yes, what i want to do is basically editing a static file, but i don't understand what you mean, could you please elaborate more your comment (and putting into an answer, so i can vote for it if it works :) )

Comment: @Written i want to change only a div and/or adding/edit a js function

Comment: @Max Yes, what I'm saying is that if there is a specific page you're changing you can reroute the url to a custom template that you provide

Comment: @Written i would prefer to don't have to do that, since what i want to change is just a minimal change. Also, the functionality that i want to change (the autocomplete) does not make an http redirect

Answer (score 0):

I will use an example of overriding static files (html and JavaScript) involving the admin app since it is built in.

Let's say you have an app `cars_app`, and you would like to change the behaviour of the admin page for the model `car`.

In the root directory of your django project, go to or create the directory `templates`. Underneath it, make the directory structure `admin/cars_app/car` (`admin/app_name/model_name`) then create the file `change_form.html`. Use the corresponding file in the `admin` app and make the changes you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reviewboard extension hooks for this purpose. Extension hooks are the primary mechanism for customizing Review Board’s appearance and behavior. Specifically for adding custom css/js please try template hook and it has the option to specific the page in which you need your custom js/css. Please refer https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.5/extending/extensions/hooks/template-hook/